# CDF to Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If I have a right-continuous nondecreasing function $F:\mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$ that tends to $0$ and $1$ as $x$ tends to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively, does $F$ necessarily induce a Borel measure $\mu$ that satisfies $\mu((-\infty,x])=F(x)$?

I know that the collection of rays $(-\infty,x]$ generate the Borel sigma-algebra, but I am not sure if this is enough to conclude that $\mu$ is a Borel measure.

Comment: A usual way is to have a measure defined on intervals first, verify its additivity, and then apply a general theorem about it extending to a sigma-algebra. Yes, the statement is true.

Comment: @justabrickinthewall Ah, Carathéodory! Thank you for the hint.